# Error Linting URL: An internal error occurred while linting the URL

Tags: facebook, url

For several months we've added link to our FB status and shared pages.  As of this week that has changed and FB appears not to be able to locate the page we try to share via URL.  Here's a URL of the page in question.

http://www.kootenaihealth.org/site/apps/nlnet/content2.aspx?c=dkLSK7OPLnKaE&b=8322323&ct=13127215&notoc=1#.UYnmIdLP2mA

In the debugger, we get the following message:

Error Linting URL: An internal error occurred while linting the URL.

We're not using the OG protocol

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this for my site and I hope this helps you.

When there is no og:image meta tag, facebook crawls your page looking for an image to use for the shared page.

In our case, an image on the page (the tumblr share button: platform.tumblr.com/v1/share_2.png) was the problem. I suspect facebook could not resolve platform.tumblr.com, and in the circumstances, died.

Hope this helps!